# how to create wso2 msf4j windows services

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/WSO2EI/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service
but unable to find MSF4J YAJSW wrapper config file at EI_HOME/wso2/msf4j/bin/yajsw/wrapper.conf
Any one manage to create windows services for wso2 msf4j profile before?
May help to share the steps?

Comment: Yes, WSO2 doesn't provide you a YAJSW wrapper for MSF4J profile in EI. Maybe it is good if you can raise a github issue on that :)

Answer (score 0):

I make follow config for yajsw. It's worked for me on Windows with **yajsw 11.03**

```
wrapper.working.dir=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.launcher.Main
wrapper.tmp.path = ${jna_tmpdir}
wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.launcher.Main
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=${wrapper_home}\/log\/wrapper.log
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
wrapper.console.title="MSF4J WSO2 Carbon"
wrapper.ntservice.name="MSF4J"
wrapper.ntservice.displayname="MSF4J Carbon"
wrapper.ntservice.description="MSF4J Carbon Kernel"
wrapper.tray = true
wrapper.tray.port = 15003
wrapper.on_exit.0=SHUTDOWN
wrapper.on_exit.default=RESTART
wrapper.filter.trigger.0=Exception
wrapper.filter.script.0=scripts\/trayMessage.gv
wrapper.filter.script.0.args=Exception
placeHolderSoGenPropsComeHere=
wrapper.console.pipestreams = true
wrapper.java.command = ${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\bin\\bootstrap
wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3 = ${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\bin\\bootstrap\\org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4 = ${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\bin\\bootstrap\\org.wso2.carbon.launcher-5.1.2.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.1 = org.wso2.carbon.launcher.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.2 = RUN
wrapper.app.parameter.3 = -Dprofile=default
wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xbootclasspath/a:
wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m
wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m
wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\logs\\heap-dump.hprof
wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8 = -Djava.endorsed.dirs=".\\bin\\bootstrap\\endorsed";${java_home}\\jre\\lib\\endorsed;${java_home}\\lib\\endorsed
wrapper.java.additional.9 = -Dcarbon.home=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j
wrapper.java.additional.10 = -Djava.command=${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.additional.11 = -Djava.io.tmpdir=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\tmp
wrapper.java.additional.12 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
wrapper.java.additional.13 = -Dcarbon.classpath=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\bin\\bootstrap;${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar;${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\bin\\bootstrap\\org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar;${carbon_home}\\wso2\\msf4j\\bin\\bootstrap\\org.wso2.carbon.launcher-5.1.2.jar
```